# curl --interface not working

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux, curl

I have 2 interfaces - eth0 and eth1. eth0 is an ethernet connection while eth1 is a 4g dongle

What works?

```
curl ifconfig.me --interface eth0
curl ifconfig.me --interface eth1
curl ifconfig.me --interface 192.168.0.102 (eth0)
```

What's not working? (Works perfectly fine on curl windows surprisingly!)

```
curl ifconfig.me --interface 192.168.11.100 (eth1)
```

I checked routing table and it seems fine?

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.102 metric 202
default via 192.168.11.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 192.168.11.100 metric 225
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.102 metric 202
192.168.11.0/24 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.100 metric 225
```

Comment: Your routing table is wrong. You can only have ONE default route.

Comment: It is far from clear WHAT you are trying to achieve. "I have 2 interfaces - eth0 and eth1" is likely to be problematic. Use **Predictable Network Interface Names**

 See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)